# How to change hostname on GNUroot debian?

Tags: networking, android

I have installed GNURoot Debian on my Android phone and I ran a server in it. Then I tried to change hostname and also assing a name to my IP. I have changed both files in `/etc/hosts/` and `/etc/hostname`.

`/etc/hosts/`:

```
127.0.0.1 mchost
127.0.1.1 mcserver
```

`/etc/hostname`:

```
mcserver
```

I tried to restart hostname using `sudo service hostname.sh start`. but it gives me an error `sudo:unable to resolve host localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

first, `127.0.0.1` must resolve to `localhost`, so you should adjust your `/etc/hosts` accordingly. Second, on Debian systems usually the command `hostname` is used to show or set the hostname, e.g. `hostname -b mcserver`.

For a correct setup in `/etc/hosts` it would also be interesting if your device always gets the same IP address in your WiFi network. Assuming it does, and that IP is `192.168.0.5`, I'd recommend the following for your `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
192.168.0.5   mchost mcserver
```

If you're unsure about the IP, simply put:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.0.1     mchost mcserver
```

But in that case, "mcserver" can only resolve locally, as that address cannot be routed.

Comment: How can i verify the change?

Comment: By calling the `hostname` command without a parameter (which should tell you the current hostname).

Comment: No it gives me `localhost`.

Comment: Not sure if "GNUroot Debian" handles things differently. I usually only edited the `/etc/hostname` file and then did a reboot (restarting network services should suffice). After that, the `hostname` command (without parameters) reflected my update.

Comment: In my hostname file, it contains `debian` and in hosts file, it contains `127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.0.1     mchost`

Comment: When i type `hostname` in GNURoot debian terminal it gives `localhost`.

Comment: Nice mix. What happens if you add `127.0.0.1 debian` to your `/etc/hosts` file? Currently, your "hostname" is not reflected there. Not sure if the two are connected, but that's the only thing I'm seeing here.

Comment: I have changed hosts file to `debian` as you said and when restarted hostname service, it gives me the error `sudo:unable to resolve host localhost`.

Comment: I didn't write to *change* that line, but to *add* it. The line `127.0.0.1 localhost` must always be present. The error message you quoted suggests you removed/replaced that line.

Comment: I have done it too.. It still gives `localhost`

Comment: Then I'm out. I use Debian on multiple machines, and that's how it always worked for me. Maybe ask the developers of GNUroot what they advise?

Comment: mm Where should i find them?

Comment: Checking the contact details on the [GNUroot Debian Playstore page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gnuroot.debian), then following the link to [their Github project page](https://github.com/corbinlc), and open [an issue](https://github.com/corbinlc/GNURootDebian/issues)?